# Prevent downloading files in a folder with many subs in it with .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a vpn server so i have access anything, if i need httpd.conf etc.

Already using the code below in .htaccess on wordpress root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on     
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domainhere\.com [NC]         
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domainhere\.com.*$ [NC]         
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|mp4)$ /maalesef [L]
```

Created another .htaccess in videos folder containing;

```
order deny,allow    
deny from all
```

Created another one in videos/english subfolder with same.

I need to protect that folder with many sub folders and mp4 files in them. Basically will be a paid video course. Users can stream it via player but can't download it. I don't want to pay Vimeo Pro or Amazon S3 since it's a budget project, maybe in future why not.

I'm also open if there's a way to protect them via converting mp4 into HLS with FFMPEG or a software called pavtube video converter ultimate.

Bonus: http://beezcode.com/hls how do they do it? Can't download with a plugin on chrome and can download the playlist m3u8 but cant open with any media player on windows.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> Created another .htaccess in videos folder containing;
>
> ```
> order deny,allow    
> deny from all
> ```
>
> Created another one in videos/english subfolder with same.

There is no need to duplicate these `.htaccess` files in subdirectories if you just want to protect everything. The `.htaccess` file applies to the current directory and the entire directory tree below it.

Note that these are Apache 2.2 directives. If you are on Apache 2.4 then you should use the following instead:

```
Require all denied
```

If you only want to protect certain file types based on file extension, then use a `<FilesMatch>` container. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|js|txt|mp4)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

However, if these files should only ever be accessed by your application, then consider storing them outside of the document root instead. The files are then protected automatically against direct/HTTP access - nothing more to do. This is the safer option as it is not dependent on any userland code (ie. `.htaccess`) nor vulnerable to server misconfiguration.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domainhere\.com [NC]         
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domainhere\.com.*$ [NC]         
> RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|mp4)$ /maalesef [L]
> ```

This is simply "hot-link" protection. Which is unreliable and easy to circumvent. In any case, if you have the above code that blocks all HTTP access then these directives are less relevant.

Comment: Just checked and it's apache 2.4. When get to work going to try Require all denied. But if it's better should i just upload these files outside of public_html and call them with a player? That's all? No need htaccess or any other stuff?

Comment: Tried Require all denied ; didn't work. Media files can be  downloaded in home/public_html/videos
Tried moving all to document root, home/domainname . Files can't be played :)

Comment: "if it's better should i just upload these files outside of public_html" - yes, as stated above, this would be preferable. This does assume that your "player" is not requesting these files over HTTP - it would need to have the appropriate permissions on the filesystem to read this file and _stream_ it back to the client.

Comment: "Tried Require all denied ; didn't work." - Are `.htaccess` files enabled in the server config? (Although if you have access to the server config then arguably you shouldn't be doing this in `.htaccess`.) Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Or any other `.htaccess` files?